# how do I add ID to dropdowns in twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-typeahead

I am using twitter bootstrap to engage a google map.

```
    $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'addresses',
  source: addresses.ttAdapter(),
  display: 'Address',
  key: 'ParcelID',
  highlight: true
}).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, data){
    $('.typeahead').val(data.ParcelID);
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[data.ParcelID], 'click');
    console.log(data.ParcelID);
});
```

it all works, but I'd like to add an ID field to the items in the dropdown.  Is that possible?  I'd like to hook a Jquery hover against the items in the dropdown.  Thanks.

Comment: To clarify you want to add an id to the individual options under a select?

Comment: correct.  twitter-typehead gives the options in the following format:  <div class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable">400  MASSACHUSETTS AVE NW APT 216 WASHINGTON, DC 20001-6801</div>  I want to add a key into each option.  Thanks.